# List all exports in ES6 Module syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, commonjs

In CommonJS, one can get all exported properties like so:

```js
module.exports.foo = 1234;
module.exports.bar = 5678;
console.log(module.exports); // <-- The variable `exports`/`module.exports` holds an object
// :)
```

How can I do the equivalent with ES6 module syntax?

```js
export const foo = 1234;
export const bar = 5678;
console.log(module.exports); // <-- Correctly holds the keys/export names, but not their values
// :(
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Umm, writing more concise code? I need an object containing all functions I export, and ideally, I don't want to repeat myself/write out the function names manually again, and instead grab the `exports` object (if such a thing even exists in ES6). I kept the question short for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Fair enough, just trying to make sure whatever I write will actually address what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ES modules have

```
import * as ModuleObj from "./foo";
```

to import a namespace object containing all of the exports of a module.

For the usecase of `module.exports`, you can have the module import itself.